# ERR_CLOSED_CONNECTION

Tags: error-handling, compiler-errors

I am working as an outsource developer in an organization, they kept encountering the ERR_CLOSED_CONNECTION problem every time they are trying to open the website in the organization's building, it works fine if its not in the area. I can open it anywhere and anytime. I think that problem is in their router, connection or devices, So I sent a link found on net on how to fix the problem, now they said that they need to change their network everytime they will access the website (they want to fix this so they don't need to change network everytime). I can't find any solution on the developer's side on how to fix the problem. Is this an issue on the developer side? or just in their network and routers?